# Condas refuses to install scipy=1.3

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda

I have removed all packages that seem to depend on scipy, but still, conda refuses to install `scipy=1.3` or `scipy=1.3.1`.

```
conda remove scipy numpy matplotlib
```

And then

```
conda install scipy=1.3.1
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                             

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with a past
explicit spec that is not an explicit spec in this operation (mkl):

  - scipy=1.3.1 -> blas[version='*|1.0',build='mkl|openblas']
  - scipy=1.3.1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
  - scipy=1.3.1 -> libgfortran-ng[version='>=7,<8.0a0']
  - scipy=1.3.1 -> libopenblas[version='>=0.3.3,<1.0a0']
  - scipy=1.3.1 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
  - scipy=1.3.1 -> mkl[version='>=2019.4,<2020.0a0']

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package pycparser conflicts for:
cffi==1.11.5=py36h9745a5d_0 -> pycparser
Package libstdcxx-ng conflicts for:
kiwisolver==1.1.0=py36he6710b0_0 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
sip==4.19.8=py36hf484d3e_0 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
gmp==6.1.2=h6c8ec71_1 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
glib==2.56.2=hd408876_0 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
ncurses==6.1=he6710b0_1 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
libffi==3.2.1=hd88cf55_4 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
expat==2.2.6=he6710b0_0 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
pcre==8.42=h439df22_0 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
pyqt==5.9.2=py36h751905a_0 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
tbb==2019.4=hfd86e86_0 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
python==3.6.9=h265db76_0 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
gst-plugins-base==1.14.0=hbbd80ab_1 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
llvmlite==0.25.0=py36hd408876_0 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
icu==58.2=h9c2bf20_1 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
tbb4py -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
Package libgcc-ng conflicts for:
xz==5.2.4=h14c3975_4 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
libxcb==1.13=h1bed415_1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
jpeg==9b=h024ee3a_2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
libuuid==1.0.3=h1bed415_2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
readline==7.0=h7b6447c_5 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
gstreamer==1.14.0=hb453b48_1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
sqlite==3.29.0=h7b6447c_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
freetype==2.9.1=h8a8886c_1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
fontconfig==2.13.0=h9420a91_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
numpy-base==1.14.3 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
zlib==1.2.11=h7b6447c_3 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
cffi==1.11.5=py36h9745a5d_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
mpc==1.1.0=h10f8cd9_1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
mpfr==4.0.1=hdf1c602_3 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
icu==58.2=h9c2bf20_1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
llvmlite==0.25.0=py36hd408876_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
kiwisolver==1.1.0=py36he6710b0_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
openssl -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
libopenblas==0.2.20 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
gmpy2==2.0.8=py36h10f8cd9_2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
pyqt==5.9.2=py36h751905a_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
sip==4.19.8=py36hf484d3e_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
tbb==2019.4=hfd86e86_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
ncurses==6.1=he6710b0_1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
libedit==3.1.20181209=hc058e9b_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
cython==0.28.3=py36h14c3975_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
libpng==1.6.37=hbc83047_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
gst-plugins-base==1.14.0=hbbd80ab_1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
line_profiler==2.1.2=py36h14c3975_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
libxml2==2.9.8=h26e45fe_1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
cryptography==2.6.1=py36h1ba5d50_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
python==3.6.9=h265db76_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
markupsafe==1.1.1=py36h7b6447c_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
expat==2.2.6=he6710b0_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
libffi==3.2.1=hd88cf55_4 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
fastcache==1.0.2=py36h14c3975_2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
tbb4py -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
glib==2.56.2=hd408876_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
dbus==1.13.2=h714fa37_1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
tk==8.6.8=hbc83047_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
gmp==6.1.2=h6c8ec71_1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
pcre==8.42=h439df22_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
Package mpfr conflicts for:
mpc==1.1.0=h10f8cd9_1 -> mpfr[version='>=4.0.1,<5.0a0']
gmpy2==2.0.8=py36h10f8cd9_2 -> mpfr[version='>=4.0.1,<5.0a0']
Package backcall conflicts for:
ipython==6.4.0=py36_0 -> backcall
Package pcre conflicts for:
glib==2.56.2=hd408876_0 -> pcre[version='>=8.42,<9.0a0']
gstreamer==1.14.0=hb453b48_1 -> pcre[version='>=8.42,<9.0a0']
Package sip conflicts for:
pyqt==5.9.2=py36h751905a_0 -> sip[version='>=4.19.4,<=4.19.8']
Package chardet conflicts for:
requests==2.18.4=py36he2e5f8d_1 -> chardet[version='>=3.0.2,<3.1.0']
Package wcwidth conflicts for:
prompt_toolkit==1.0.15=py36h17d85b1_0 -> wcwidth
Package libffi conflicts for:
python==3.6.9=h265db76_0 -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<4.0a0']
glib==2.56.2=hd408876_0 -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<4.0a0']
cffi==1.11.5=py36h9745a5d_0 -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<4.0a0']
gstreamer==1.14.0=hb453b48_1 -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<4.0a0']
Package zlib conflicts for:
python==3.6.9=h265db76_0 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
tk==8.6.8=hbc83047_0 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
llvmlite==0.25.0=py36hd408876_0 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
libpng==1.6.37=hbc83047_0 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
gst-plugins-base==1.14.0=hbbd80ab_1 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
freetype==2.9.1=h8a8886c_1 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
libxml2==2.9.8=h26e45fe_1 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
glib==2.56.2=hd408876_0 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
Package cffi conflicts for:
cryptography==2.6.1=py36h1ba5d50_0 -> cffi[version='>=1.7']
Package mkl-service conflicts for:
scipy=1.3.1 -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0']
Package expat conflicts for:
dbus==1.13.2=h714fa37_1 -> expat[version='>=2.2.5,<3.0a0']
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> expat[version='>=2.2.6,<3.0a0']
Package pygments conflicts for:
ipython==6.4.0=py36_0 -> pygments
prompt_toolkit==1.0.15=py36h17d85b1_0 -> pygments
Package setuptools conflicts for:
pip -> setuptools
pygments==2.2.0=py36h0d3125c_0 -> setuptools
cython==0.28.3=py36h14c3975_0 -> setuptools
wheel==0.33.4=py36_0 -> setuptools
jinja2==2.10.1=py36_0 -> setuptools
Package icu conflicts for:
fontconfig==2.13.0=h9420a91_0 -> icu[version='>=58.2,<59.0a0']
libxml2==2.9.8=h26e45fe_1 -> icu[version='>=58.2,<59.0a0']
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> icu[version='>=58.2,<59.0a0']
Package libgfortran-ng conflicts for:
libopenblas==0.2.20 -> libgfortran-ng[version='>=7,<8.0a0|>=7.2.0,<8.0a0']
numpy-base==1.14.3 -> libgfortran-ng[version='>=7,<8.0a0']
Package idna conflicts for:
urllib3==1.22=py36hbe7ace6_0 -> idna[version='>=2.0.0']
cryptography==2.6.1=py36h1ba5d50_0 -> idna[version='>=2.1']
requests==2.18.4=py36he2e5f8d_1 -> idna[version='>=2.5,<2.7']
Package certifi conflicts for:
urllib3==1.22=py36hbe7ace6_0 -> certifi
setuptools==41.0.1=py36_0 -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
requests==2.18.4=py36he2e5f8d_1 -> certifi[version='>=2017.4.17']
Package ncurses conflicts for:
python==3.6.9=h265db76_0 -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0']
readline==7.0=h7b6447c_5 -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0']
libedit==3.1.20181209=hc058e9b_0 -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0']
Package fastcache conflicts for:
sympy==1.1.1=py36hc6d1c1c_0 -> fastcache
Package libpng conflicts for:
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> libpng[version='>=1.6.35,<1.7.0a0']
fontconfig==2.13.0=h9420a91_0 -> libpng[version='>=1.6.34,<1.7.0a0']
freetype==2.9.1=h8a8886c_1 -> libpng[version='>=1.6.34,<1.7.0a0']
Package cryptography conflicts for:
urllib3==1.22=py36hbe7ace6_0 -> cryptography[version='>=1.3.4']
pyopenssl==18.0.0=py36_0 -> cryptography[version='>=2.2.1']
Package libxcb conflicts for:
gst-plugins-base==1.14.0=hbbd80ab_1 -> libxcb[version='>=1.13,<2.0a0']
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> libxcb[version='>=1.13,<2.0a0']
Package glib conflicts for:
dbus==1.13.2=h714fa37_1 -> glib[version='>=2.56.1,<3.0a0']
gstreamer==1.14.0=hb453b48_1 -> glib[version='>=2.56.1,<3.0a0']
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> glib[version='>=2.56.2,<3.0a0']
gst-plugins-base==1.14.0=hbbd80ab_1 -> glib[version='>=2.56.1,<3.0a0']
Package sqlite conflicts for:
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> sqlite[version='>=3.25.3,<4.0a0']
python==3.6.9=h265db76_0 -> sqlite[version='>=3.29.0,<4.0a0']
Package tk conflicts for:
python==3.6.9=h265db76_0 -> tk[version='>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0']
Package pickleshare conflicts for:
ipython==6.4.0=py36_0 -> pickleshare
Package urllib3 conflicts for:
requests==2.18.4=py36he2e5f8d_1 -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<1.23']
Package mpmath conflicts for:
sympy==1.1.1=py36hc6d1c1c_0 -> mpmath[version='>=0.19']
Package dbus conflicts for:
pyqt==5.9.2=py36h751905a_0 -> dbus[version='>=1.12.2,<2.0a0']
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> dbus[version='>=1.13.2,<2.0a0']
Package freetype conflicts for:
fontconfig==2.13.0=h9420a91_0 -> freetype[version='>=2.9.1,<3.0a0']
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> freetype[version='>=2.9.1,<3.0a0']
Package ipython_genutils conflicts for:
traitlets==4.3.2=py36h674d592_0 -> ipython_genutils
Package mkl conflicts for:
numpy-base==1.14.3 -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.2,<2019.0a0']
Package six conflicts for:
prompt_toolkit==1.0.15=py36h17d85b1_0 -> six[version='>=1.9.0']
traitlets==4.3.2=py36h674d592_0 -> six
cryptography==2.6.1=py36h1ba5d50_0 -> six[version='>=1.4.1']
python-dateutil==2.8.0=py36_0 -> six[version='>=1.5']
pyopenssl==18.0.0=py36_0 -> six[version='>=1.5.2']
cycler==0.10.0=py36h93f1223_0 -> six
Package traitlets conflicts for:
ipython==6.4.0=py36_0 -> traitlets[version='>=4.2']
Package pexpect conflicts for:
ipython==6.4.0=py36_0 -> pexpect
Package markupsafe conflicts for:
jinja2==2.10.1=py36_0 -> markupsafe[version='>=0.23']
Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
openssl -> ca-certificates
Package xz conflicts for:
gstreamer==1.14.0=hb453b48_1 -> xz[version='>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
python==3.6.9=h265db76_0 -> xz[version='>=5.2.4,<6.0a0']
libxml2==2.9.8=h26e45fe_1 -> xz[version='>=5.2.4,<6.0a0']
gst-plugins-base==1.14.0=hbbd80ab_1 -> xz[version='>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
Package mpc conflicts for:
gmpy2==2.0.8=py36h10f8cd9_2 -> mpc
Package qt conflicts for:
pyqt==5.9.2=py36h751905a_0 -> qt[version='5.9.*,>=5.9.4,<5.10.0a0']
Package blas conflicts for:
numpy-base==1.14.3 -> blas[version='*|*|1.0',build='mkl|openblas']
Package parso conflicts for:
jedi==0.12.0=py36_1 -> parso
Package openssl conflicts for:
python==3.6.9=h265db76_0 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a']
cryptography==2.6.1=py36h1ba5d50_0 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a']
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> openssl=1.1
Package gstreamer conflicts for:
gst-plugins-base==1.14.0=hbbd80ab_1 -> gstreamer[version='>=1.14.0,<2.0a0']
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> gstreamer[version='>=1.14.0,<1.15.0a0']
Package fontconfig conflicts for:
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> fontconfig[version='>=2.13.0,<3.0a0']
Package gmp conflicts for:
gmpy2==2.0.8=py36h10f8cd9_2 -> gmp[version='>=6.1.2']
mpfr==4.0.1=hdf1c602_3 -> gmp[version='>=6.1.2']
mpc==1.1.0=h10f8cd9_1 -> gmp[version='>=6.1.2']
Package ipython conflicts for:
line_profiler==2.1.2=py36h14c3975_0 -> ipython[version='>=0.13']
Package decorator conflicts for:
ipython==6.4.0=py36_0 -> decorator
traitlets==4.3.2=py36h674d592_0 -> decorator
Package pip conflicts for:
python==3.6.9=h265db76_0 -> pip
Package jedi conflicts for:
ipython==6.4.0=py36_0 -> jedi[version='>=0.10']
Package wheel conflicts for:
pip -> wheel
Package gst-plugins-base conflicts for:
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> gst-plugins-base[version='>=1.14.0,<1.15.0a0']
Package libuuid conflicts for:
fontconfig==2.13.0=h9420a91_0 -> libuuid[version='>=1.0.3,<2.0a0']
Package numpy conflicts for:
numpy-base==1.14.3 -> numpy==1.14.3[build='py36h28100ab_1|py27hcd700cb_1|py27h28100ab_1|py35h28100ab_1|py35hcd700cb_1|py36hcd700cb_1']
scipy=1.3.1 -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0']
Package ptyprocess conflicts for:
pexpect==4.6.0=py36_0 -> ptyprocess[version='>=0.5']
Package libopenblas conflicts for:
numpy-base==1.14.3 -> libopenblas[version='>=0.2.20,<0.2.21.0a0']
Package jpeg conflicts for:
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> jpeg[version='>=9b,<10a']
Package libxml2 conflicts for:
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> libxml2[version='>=2.9.8,<2.10.0a0']
fontconfig==2.13.0=h9420a91_0 -> libxml2[version='>=2.9.8,<2.10.0a0']
Package readline conflicts for:
python==3.6.9=h265db76_0 -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0']
Package asn1crypto conflicts for:
cryptography==2.6.1=py36h1ba5d50_0 -> asn1crypto[version='>=0.21.0']
Package simplegeneric conflicts for:
ipython==6.4.0=py36_0 -> simplegeneric[version='>0.8']
Package gmpy2 conflicts for:
sympy==1.1.1=py36hc6d1c1c_0 -> gmpy2[version='>=2.0.8']
Package _libgcc_mutex conflicts for:
libgcc-ng==9.1.0=hdf63c60_0 -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
Package tbb conflicts for:
tbb4py -> tbb[version='>=2018.0.4|>=2018.0.5|>=2019.0|>=2019.1|>=2019.4|>=2019.8']
Package prompt_toolkit conflicts for:
ipython==6.4.0=py36_0 -> prompt_toolkit[version='>=1.0.4,<2.0.0']
Package intel-openmp conflicts for:
mkl==2018.0.2 -> intel-openmp
Package tbb4py conflicts for:
numpy-base==1.14.3 -> tbb4py
Package pyopenssl conflicts for:
urllib3==1.22=py36hbe7ace6_0 -> pyopenssl[version='>=0.14']
Package libedit conflicts for:
sqlite==3.29.0=h7b6447c_0 -> libedit[version='>=3.1.20181209,<3.2.0a0']
Package pysocks conflicts for:
urllib3==1.22=py36hbe7ace6_0 -> pysocks[version='>=1.5.6,<2.0,!=1.5.7']
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Try `pip install scipy=1.3` in anaconda prompt

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar I'm worried that there's something fundamental wrong about my composition of packages. To the extend that `pip` is a less sophisticated program than `conda`, I'm worried that ignoring `conda`'s warnings and using `pip` is going to worsen the state of my package.s

Answer (score 1):

We suggest you to create a conda environment and try installing scipy 1.3.1.

Create a conda environment using :

`conda create -n <env_name> -c intel python=3.6`

Activate the environment :

`source activate <env_name>`

Install the required package using conda command :

`conda install scipy = 1.3.1`